# mysql order by string with array key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I will like to order leagues (league of legends) in MySQL search.

My array:

```
$leagues = array(0 => 'unranked', 1 => 'bronze', 2 => 'silver', 
                 3 => 'gold', 4 => 'platin', 5 => 'diamond');
```

My MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts order by league
```

It's ordering by alphabetically but i need to order by array key (diamond > platin > gold > silver > bronze > unranked)

How can I do this with array key?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful because diamond, platin, etc., are not keys, but array values.

Considering that your league column on accounts table has numeric values (0 to 5) try to add a "DESC" on your query:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts order by league DESC
```

If your league column on accounts table has text values (diamond, platin, gold, silver, bronze and unranked) your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY FIELD(league, "diamond", "platin", "gold", "silver", "bronze", "unranked")
```

Comment: Yep this will work if he has a `league` (text) field. But it looks like it might be ID's (0,1,2,3,4,5) considering he's tried to use the array to map it.

Comment: thanks, it solved my problem !